# Create a dynamic survey

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I have a wizard which allow the user to input different questions and answers that they want to appear on the survey. On clicking on submit, the survey should be generated, that is the xhtml (jsf page) . Anyone can tell me how can I do this? It's a java web application using spring,hibernate,primefaces,jsf 2.0.

Comment: @Samantha Whats the actual problem here ?

Comment: How do i actually write this xhtml? Basically if i knew what are the questions the survey will contain, it's easy. I will design my xhtml with these questions. But now I don't know what are the questions that will displayed on the xhtml, it's only after completing the wizard, that I will know this. So how do i produce an xhtml on the fly with these questions created from the wizard?

Comment: You should save all questions and possible answers to database (so you can show them later to user). Depending on question and answer type, you should get list of questions from database and loop trough that list to create form (depends if you want all question on one page or lazy loaded one per page, this will need some more logic buts its up to you to decide). Check on this link there is simple example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gke4dbW-5zg